# How to get reference to App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I am trying to implement MVVM pattern for my Windows Phone application. I have my Views in one project and App.xaml in another project. I added property IsTrial to App.xaml but I can't reach it from View by this code:

```
if ((Application.Current as App).IsTrial)
```

Because I didn't reference first project with App class but I can't do that because that would cause a circular dependency. What can I do? How can I access App class? Thanks

Comment: Can't you pass that information into your viewmodel when you're instantiating it? Your views should really only be pulling data from the viewmodel.

Comment: I usually create a static ApplicationInfo class in a shared project with these kind of properties. That way its easy to access global information from any project related to the current application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface in your Views project:

```
public interface ISupportTrial
{
   bool IsTrial { get; }
}
```

Implement the interface in App.xaml.cs:

```
public class App: Application, ISupportTrial
{
...
}
```

Change the code where you access the app:

```
var trialApp = Application.Current as ISupportTrial;
if (trialApp == null)
{
   throw new NotSupportedException("Application.Current should implement ISupportTrial");
}
else if (trialApp.IsTrial)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

---

NOTE: Although this will probably work, I don't think that it's a good practice to access Application.Current. You might want to read some articles about Inversion of Control and Dependency injection.